# Do I need to recompile my app when Ad Hoc provision profile expires?

Tags: ios, mobile

I am using Ad Hoc provision profile together with distribution certificate. Do I need to recompile my app when the certificate is expired or revoked?

Comment: You are asking which purpose?

Comment: I am asking because I need to know whether my app will stop working or/and ipa file will not be able to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Once you certificate is expired. If you are using the ad hoc profile then  the app will stop working and also you cannot install the ipa file.

You need create a build using the **renewed certificate**.

Comment: Any other user to confirm it, please?